# How do I download content from firebase storage and keep that content on the user's phone?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have an app in which I have one user upload videos to firebase, which works fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to download the video and keep that video on the user's phone.

Comment: check this package available : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_downloader

Comment: Is the app `iOS` or `Android`? Add the tag or mention it in the question.

Comment: It is for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download your file you can use [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider)  plugin to access device storage and save your file there.

I would recommend the Document directory which can be accessed using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` to save your file.

Here is the idea of doing it.

```
String directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
File file = File('$directory/your_file_name');
http.Response response = await http.get(your_url_here);
file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes)
```